# Magento 2 issue diffence CSS content on same file domain/pub/static/.../file.css and domain/static/.../files.css?

Tags: magento2, static-content-deploy, filesystem

I have problem with magento 2.2.7 but cannot find way fix so hope someonce can help.
File name: `domain/pub/static/.../file.css` and `domain/static/.../file.css`.

After I changed content of file.css and push to server just only `domain/pub/static/.../file.css` apply changed. I tried **push cache** and **deploy** but content of `domain/static/.../file.css` not change. My current website load style file via url `domain/static/.../file.css`.

I got this after STORE > CONFIGURATION > ADVANCED > DEVELOPER > Storage Configuration for Media > CLICK button **Synchronize**.

I need appy my change on `domain/static/.../file.css`. Anybody know how to do that?

Note: I tried `Sign Static Files` change to **Yes** and **No** but not luck. I flushed cache after change any config option.

**Updated:** this content of file after load `pub/static` and `/static/` cache be flushed and browser cache be cleaned
[image]
[image]

Thanks advance!

Comment: try removing files inside `pub/static` folder except for `.htaccess` and check if changes you made will apply

Comment: thanks u, I tried this way already.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to regenerate static files using the cli command:
**bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy**

Comment: I run this many times

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED,
This issue come from cloudflare CDN just go to Purge Cache on cloudflare.